# Autowiring bean in Session Listener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I need to Autowire a service class annotated with @Service annotation in my  session listener class as I need to perform some DB operation on session destroyed method. I am not able to autowire the service class as I have added the listener in my web.xml and it is no longer spring managed. I have tried several options(workarounds) like getting a bean from application context via servlet context but I am not getting any beans in that way.

Following are my classes:-
MyService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FxTransactionService{
//some autowirings
public void performDBoperation(Long id)
{
//business logic
}
}
```

Session Listener:

```
     public class SessionHandler implements HttpSessionListener {
            private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

            @Autowired
            private MyService myService;

            @Override
            public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Session created");
                ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(arg0.getSession()
                    .getServletContext());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(context.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
//This gives me empty list
            }

            @Override
            public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    Long id = (Long) arg0.getSession().getAttribute("Id");
                myService.performDBoperation(id);

            }

        }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

<web-app>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.abc.controller.SessionHandler</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>preAuthHeaderAdditionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.abc.filter.PreAuthHeaderAdditionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>preAuthHeaderAdditionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- <filter> <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name> <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class> 
        </filter> <filter-mapping> <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping> -->


</web-app>
```

Comment: how you fixed it ?

Comment: @Saumyaraj have you find any solution to do so? I'm in a similar situation

Answer (score 2):

First install the Spring listener ContextLoaderListener.
In your own listener you can access the context using WebApplicationContextUtils. 
It is not autowiring though, you  have to fetch the required bean/service yourself.

Comment: I had tried that as mentioned in question but it didnt work.